# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::save() when running a Laravel Task Schedule Command

Tags: laravel

I am trying  to schedule a campaign that runs when

> subendsat is greater or equal  to current time

`subendsat` is a column in user table

> In my commands, I have this

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use App\User;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class ChangeRole extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'command:update';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'This Changes Role When The Subscription Expires';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        //
        $user = User::where('subendsat', '>=', Carbon::now())->get();
        $user->role = 'subscriber';
        $user->save();

    }
}
```

> In my Kernel, I have this

```
protected $commands = [
    //
    'App\Console\Commands\ChangeRole',
];

/**
 * Define the application's command schedule.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
 * @return void
 */
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
     $schedule->command('command:update')
              ->daily();
}
```

> I create a basic task like this in windows
>   I have this inmy .bat file
>
> c:\xampp\php\php.exe artisan schedule:run 1>> NUL 2>&1

1. Go to Windows Task Scheduler
2. Click Create a basic task, choose When I login trigger and then choose to Start a program -> your .bat file.
3. Check Open properties dialog option and click Finish.
4. In task properties click Triggers, then click New and add new trigger Repeat task every - 1 minute.

But when I run the command

> php artisan command:update, it returned error
>
> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::save()

But this is not updating my database when it runs. I don't know what I am doing. Can someone advise? thanks.

Comment: what .bat file? Where is it & whats it content?

Comment: I have this in bat file c:\xampp\php\php.exe artisan schedule:run 1>> NUL 2>&1

Comment: I've never worked with Windows. So a quick google search gave me this https://quantizd.com/how-to-use-laravel-task-scheduler-on-windows-10/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you posted would not throw that error... You don't have an instance of the `Builder` class, as `->get()` returns a `Collection`. But regardless, modifying a property of a `Collection`, via `$user->role = 'subscriber';` is not valid... You need to loop over `$users` (**name your variables properly**) and update each `$user`:

```
$users = User::where('subendsat', '>=', Carbon::now())->get();
foreach ($users as $user) {
  $user->role = 'subscriber';
  $user->save();
}
```

Or call a batch `update()`:

```
User::where('subendsat', '>=', Carbon::now())->update([
  'role' => 'subscriber'
]);
```

Comment: This fix the error, but the scheduler is not working. Please any idea on how I can fix this?

Comment: "*scheduler is not working*" - What do you mean by that? When you say "something is not working", you generally need to explain why, as on its own, that statement is not very useful...

Comment: Don't forget to run the scheduler from your server's OS with a chron job: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/scheduling#introduction

Comment: @TimLewis. I am running a task scheduler to update user database when a `subendsat` column >= current time. But when I run the action/command. The column doesn't get updated. That's what I mean't it not working. I created a task in windows already to run the cron already.

Comment: Do you have any records in your database where `subendsat` is **greater** than `Carbon::now()`? Easiest way is to take your query and run it somewhere where you can do a `dd()` on the result: `dd(User::where('subendsat', '>=', Carbon::now())->get())` will let you view all the results, or `dd(User::where('subendsat', '>=', Carbon::now())->count());` will let you display the number of rows that would be updated.

Answer (score 1):

Yes because you return a collection, not a single entry.

You can mass update your entries :

```
User::update(['role' => 'subscriber'])
      ->where('subendsat', '>=', Carbon::now());
```

But I think you can't do this, you need to update the `role_id` field :

```
$roleSubscriber = Role::where('name', 'subscriber')->first();

User::update(['role_id' => $role->getKey()])
      ->where('subendsat', '>=', Carbon::now());
```